# Converting Excel file to Google Sheets destroys formulas with HYPERLINK

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have an Excel file where I create an internal link. Let's say I have cell A1 in sheet2 that links to sheet1 cell B2, then I'd put the following formula into sheet2!A1:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'sheet1'!B2", "Back to sheet1")
```

However, when I now upload this Excel file to Google sheets (doesn't matter if I just upload the Excel file or if I convert it to a true Gsheets document once uploaded), these hyperlinks return an error. Looking into the respective cell, the formula gets converted to (two equal signs!):

```
==HYPERLINK("#'sheet1'!B2", "Back to sheet1")
```

But even removing the double equal sign doesn't help.

So long story short: is there a way to automatically correctly convert Excel HYPERLINk formulas into Google sheets hyperlinks?

Comment: Do the arguments match in the excel version to the googlesheets version?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a proper `HYPERLINK` in google sheets is done like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A1"; "Back to sheet1")
```

[image]

where GID is the unique ID of the sheet